# PSMTabBarControl doesn't work in xcode 4.0

Tags: xcode, tabs, browser, fatal-error, psmtabbarcontrol

I am new to xcode and I'm trying to create a web browser with tabs. So I found out about [PSMTabBarControl](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html) which allows me to control and edit the tabs as I desire... So I downloaded the framework and dragged it into the frameworks folder of my application, but when I try to run the application I get the same error:
"0__dyld_dyld_fatal_error"

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get the Ibplugin to work, since Xcode 4 dropped support for ibplugins.

However, PSMTabBarController itself works fine. You just have to drop an NSView in Xcode that's 22px high and window width, change the class to PSMTabBarController and then set the tabs up programmatically.

here's my fork that compiles to a .framework perfectly in Xcode 4:
https://github.com/dorianj/PSMTabBarControl

Answer (score 0):

That source code isn't managed anymore, so there seems to have been changes to frameworks it links to. Unless you have the framework sources or updated code to build, you most likely wont be able to get this to work.

Comment: That's too bad, but thanks for the answer. Do you know how I can get my tabs to look like safari's by any chance?

Comment: Not from experience no, but I am sure there are a number of custom classes that achieve this. You can also try contacting the author of `PSMTabBarControl` to see if you can get the latest source, and go from there.